# Export from Excel to DataGridView, missing string

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, datatable

I have problem with export from Excel to dataTable. When I have too many text in a cell, it export to dataGridView but some text is missing. I think because my DataTable is limited to some characters. Can anyone help me with it?

Example in Excel Cell I have :

```
15 ha
14 ee
13 oo
...
2  dd
1  qq
0  rr
```

and when i export to dataGridView i just have

```
15 ha
14 ee
13 oo
...
till 5 vv
and the rest can not be seen
```

the code i use:

```
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + userSelectedFilePath2 + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");

            conn.Open();

            string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "ABC");
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this string is most probably in A1 cell of the Excel Sheet so it is mapped as a header string of your `DataGridView` control. Put it in a A2 cell and you'll get the complete text.

Comment: hmm... that won't solve my problem. I have many cells like that not only in A1 or A2. I think OLEDB read my Excel not completly

Comment: no, my cells are in U30, B21 ... I tried without columns header  HDR=YES but it gives me the same. Oledb doesn't read too big text in cell

Comment: OK, so it reads everything but doesn't display it, right?. So the problem is OLEDB or DataGridView that doesn't display all text?

Comment: The problem is of course DataGridView, you should set the Width and possibly Height of the cells of the DataGridView control.

Comment: You can try with dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

Comment: i tried your code but the result is the same. missing text can not be displayed

Comment: Set this before you bind your data to the datagridview control

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19290/discussion-between-uni-le-and-nikolad-nick)

Comment: I cant I'm not at the computer anymore. I'm writing from my cellphone.

Comment: i tried it before dataadapter.fill but its the same and before string query, result the same

Comment: And what is in the datagridview column headers after you load your data?There shouldn't be a string that you are processing but some text that is naming that column.

Comment: after i use your code, the columns headers are very width, but the name and result are the same like before. Means that headers name are like name from excel tables

Comment: Then I can't help you,check for some strange charcters in your text.

Comment: i have checked many times, no strange characters at all. It happens not just ine one cell, but in many cells, which text are too long